# last div I added not positioning to bottom of page

Tags: html, css, css-position

I don't know what's causing this..
I added a div onto my page that is going to be the wrapper for my footer 
**(class = main_foot)**
and it's stuck in the top left corner.

***goal: Move the div underneath div class="main_content"***

I checked to make sure the element's class was correct in the style sheet, position tags, idk. It just doesn't seem to move.

Hopefully someone can notice the problem. 
It's the last div I added.

***JS fiddle:*** http://jsfiddle.net/73mK8/1/

**Header.php**

```
<html>

<head>

    <html>
    <head>
    <title> Crazy Fat Wrap* </title>
    <link href="../CSS/nav.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="../CSS/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="../CSS/body.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="../CSS/stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

    <script type="text/javascript"><!--//--><![CDATA[//><!--

        sfHover = function() {
            var sfEls = document.getElementById("nav").getElementsByTagName("LI");
            for (var i=0; i<sfEls.length; i++) {
                sfEls[i].onmouseover=function() {
                    this.className+=" sfhover";
                }
                sfEls[i].onmouseout=function() {
                    this.className=this.className.replace(new RegExp(" sfhover\\b"), "");
                }
            }
        }
        if (window.attachEvent) window.attachEvent("onload", sfHover);

        //--><!]]></script>





</head>

<body>
<div class="solid_banner">
<h1> Crazy Fat Wrap </h1>
<!--above the Main Nav -->
<ul class="soc">
    <li><a href="#"><img src="../images/soc/Facebook.png"></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img src="../images/soc/GMail.png"></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img src="../images/soc/Contacts.png"></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img src="../images/soc/Phone.png"></a></li>

</ul>
</div>


<div class="nav_bar">

<?php include('nav.php'); ?>

<!--///// head_bar div-->
</div>


<div class="orange_strip">

</div>



<div class="feat_head">
    <img src="../images/shanesfacebook.jpg">


</div>

<div class="main_content">

    <div class="main_content_img">
<!--                         /// /// main content article -->
    <img src="../images/flag.jpg">


    </div>
<!--                    /// main content article -->
<div class="main_content_copy">

    <h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>
    <article>
    Fusce auctor, metus eu ultricies vulputate, sapien nibh faucibus ligula, eget sollicitudin augue risus et dolor. Aenean pellentesque, tortor in cursus mattis, ante diam malesuada ligula, ac vestibulum neque turpis ut enim. Cras ornare. Proin ac nisi. Praesent laoreet ante tempor urna. In imperdiet. Nam ut metus et orci fermentum nonummy. Cras vel nunc. Donec feugiat neque eget purus. Quisque rhoncus. Phasellus tempus massa aliquet urna. Integer fringilla quam eget dolor. Curabitur mattis. Aliquam ac lacus. In congue, odio ut tristique adipiscing, diam leo fermentum ipsum, nec sollicitudin dui quam et tortor. Proin id neque ac pede egestas lacinia. Curabitur non odio.

    </article>
</div>




</div>


<!--        foooter . php begin --- >

<div class="main_foot">



    <div class="main_footer_copy">
<!-- /////////// Main Footer Article-->
        <h2>Call To Action</h2>
        <article>
            Fusce auctor, metus eu ultricies vulputate, sapien nibh faucibus ligula, eget sollicitudin augue risus et dolor. Aenean pellentesque, tortor in cursus mattis, ante diam malesuada ligula, ac vestibulum neque turpis ut enim. Cras ornare. Proin ac nisi. Praesent laoreet ante tempor urna. In imperdiet. Nam ut metus et orci fermentum nonummy. Cras vel nunc. Donec feugiat neque eget purus. Quisque rhoncus. Phasellus tempus massa aliquet urna. Integer fringilla quam eget dolor. Curabitur mattis. Aliquam ac lacus. In congue, odio ut tristique adipiscing, diam leo fermentum ipsum, nec sollicitudin dui quam et tortor. Proin id neque ac pede egestas lacinia. Curabitur non odio.

        </article>

      </div>

    <!-- /////////// Main Footer Img-->

        <div class="main_footer_img">
            <!--                         /// /// main content article -->
            <a href="#"><img src="../images/shanesbizcard.jpg"></a>


        </div>




</div>



</body>
</html>
```

***stylesheet.css***

```
.solid_banner {
    width: 100%;
    height: 70px;

    position: fixed;
    z-index: 55;
    top: 0;


    background: rgba(255, 115, 67, 0.9);


}

.solid_banner h1 {
padding:19px 5%;

}

.nav_bar {
    z-index: 55;
    position: fixed;
    top: 70px;
    right: 25%;
    align-content: center;
}

.space {

    height: 3000px;
}


.soc {
    position: fixed;
    list-style:none;
    top: 0;
    right: 50px;
}
.soc li {
    display:inline-block;
    padding: 0 5px;

}
.soc img {
    height: 40px;
    width: 55px;
    opacity: .7;
}

.soc img:hover {
    opacity: 1;

}

.feat_head {
  position: absolute;
    margin: 205px 15%;
    width: auto;
    height: 550px;
    z-index: 30;
    border: 10px solid rgba(0,0,0,.7);
}

.feat_head img {

    width: 100%;
    height: 550px;

}


.main_content {
    background: #ff7343;
    position:absolute;
    margin: 815px 15%;
    width: auto;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px black;

/* //// /    /// /   ///   85%*/


}

.main_content_img {
    width: 25%;
    display:inline-block;
    padding: 2.5%;
}


.main_content_img img {
    border-radius: 5px;

}

.main_content_copy {

    width: 45%;
    height: 500px;
    padding: 0 10%;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
    text-align: left;
    padding-top: 100px;
}

.main_content_copy article {
    height: 500px;
    width: 100%;

}

.main_content_copy h2 {

    text-align: center;
}

.main_content_copy article:first-letter {

    font-size: 1.3em;
    font-weight:bold;

}
```

///// problem began here

```
.main_foot {

    background: #ff7343;
    position:absolute;
    margin: 1915px 15% 0 !important;
    width: auto;
    height: 900px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px black;
}
```

Comment: Why the position: absolute? Why not just keep it in the normal flow of the page?

Comment: Indeed, it's the absolute positioned elements causing this behavior.

Comment: Okay, yeah your right. I went back after and removed all the absolute positions, I just have to make use of margin: -value; to move it back.

Thanks. Simpler than i was expecting.

Answer (score 0):

Try these changes

css change

```
.feat_head {
    margin: 205px 15%;
    width: auto;
    height: 550px;
    z-index: 30;
    border: 10px solid rgba(0,0,0,.7);
}
.main_content {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    background: #ff7343;
    width: auto;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px black;
}
.main_content_copy {
    width: 45%;
    height: 500px;
    padding: 0 10%;
    display:block;
    float: left;
    vertical-align:top;
    text-align: left;
    padding-top: 100px;
}
.main_foot {
    clear: both;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    background: #ccc;
    width: 100%;
    height: 900px;
    border: 1px solid #F00;
}
```

html change

```
<!--        foooter . php begin --- >
```

to

```
<!--        foooter . php begin --->
```

Comment: thanks, i'll look closer at what you did, but I had to ask what was the last part? 
footer.php comment change ? I'm slightly confused.

Comment: there is a space here `--- >` it should be like `--->`

Comment: oh! nice attention to detail

Comment: You don't need absolute positioning, I just change positioned div to float one after another.

Comment: Wow, that comment was actually the underlying problem.
I removed the position:absolute, which leads to better code so +1 for that, but then my problem moved from top right corner to bottom right lol. I changed the comment and it popped into the right place.
So thankyou, I would've never seen that.

Comment: you also need to remove `position:absolute;` from `.main_foot` see update in my answer